# Is there anything in the Coliseum?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I stumbled upon the Coliseum in BotW. It seems to be an important place, but after killing the Lynel and a few enemies, it seems there is nothing else here, not even a Korok seed.

Is there anything to do that I missed in the Coliseum, or is it just empty?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this article](https://mic.com/articles/171816/breath-of-the-wild-coliseum-guide-how-to-find-the-coliseum-filled-with-rare-loot#.Wuf05VP5L), the whole point of the coliseum is to get the weapons of the strong enemies within it:

> The whole gimmick to this area is that it's full of the most powerful enemies relative to where you are in the game, and each of them is wielding rare weapons for you to take once you've disposed of them.
>
> Most importantly, every single enemy has some kind of elemental weapon. Flameblades, thunderblades and frostspears are plentiful in the coliseum.

From what I've read, the strongest enemies in the game (excluding bosses) are within the coliseum, making it a challenge to get their weapons.  There are also [two treasure chest](https://samurai-gamers.com/legend-zelda-breath-wild/easter-egg-coliseum-ruins/) at the top of the ruins.

Comment: Good thing to take note of! If I dont have any flameblades to light fires through hyrule I know where to stop! (I'm a little pyromaniac, plz send help)

Comment: 'Most powerful enemies' Yeah right. Went in pretty late game so except the silver lynel, I pretty much mopped the floor with them :p

Answer (score 2):

There is also a Korok on a ledge beneath a chest above the entrance and under a rock